# Regular expression needed to replace JavaScript code in HTML files

Tags: notepad++, html, regex, javascript, newlines

I need a regular expression that works in [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) to remove multiline JavaScript references in several hundred HTML files. The code I want to remove looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function ehlp_showtip(current,e,text)
{
  if ((parseInt(navigator.appVersion) == 4) && (navigator.appName == 'Netscape'))
  {
    document.tooltip.document.write("<layer bgColor='yellow' style='border:1px solid black;font-size:12px;'>"+ text + "<\/layer>");
    document.tooltip.document.close();
    document.tooltip.left=e.pageX+5;
    document.tooltip.top=e.pageY+5;
    document.tooltip.visibility="show";
  }
}
function ehlp_hidetip()
{
  document.tooltip.visibility="hidden";
}
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
<!--
function reDo() {
  if (innerWidth != origWidth || innerHeight != origHeight)
     location.reload();
}
if ((parseInt(navigator.appVersion) == 4) && (navigator.appName == "Netscape")) {
        origWidth = innerWidth;
        origHeight = innerHeight;
        onresize = reDo;
}
onerror = null; 
//-->
</script>
```

Obviously I want to replace everything from `<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">` to the closing script tag.

Comment: On a lighter note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11054846/1081936), recent versions of Notepad++ can deal with multiline regexes. So, if you have the option:

```
[ ] . matches newline
```

select it and try this regex:

```
<script.*?/script>
```

**Backup your files before doing this**. I don't use Notepad++ (I prefer the glorious thing that are regexes in [Perl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) or [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) :)), so I can't test it.

Comment: for some reason that is only matching single lines even tho I have the '. matches newline' option checked :(

Comment: Do you have 'Regular expression' checked. I've just tried this and it works in the latest version of Notepad++.

Comment: @Richie086, just making sure you get snowdude's comment.

Comment: I had to modify this slightly, but overall I was able to make it work for my purposes.   Thanks for answering.